# Filtrar respuesta de API

Tags: javascript, json, api

Necesito filtrar una respuesta de una  API dependiendo de su id con JavaScript,tengo en html una caja de texto,cuando yo escriba un numero 1 o 2 me lo filtre según el id

[image]

Este es mi código

```
function filtrar(){

const url = 'https://servexusinc.com/api/Model/getTestData';

fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {

        let element = document.getElementById('element')
        document.getElementById("api").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data)

        //console.log(data)
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

Comment: Edita la pregunta, copia y pega el json en lugar de una imagen representando el json. Será más fácil para la comunidad poder darte un mejor aporte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer de este modo:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>JS Bin</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <input id="api" type="text">
      <div id="texto"></div>
    <script>
    
    let busqueda = document.getElementById("api")
    
    function hola(id) {
      busqueda.addEventListener("keyup", () => {
    
          fetch(`https://servexusinc.com/api/Model/getTestData/${id.value}`)
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(data => {
    
              let element = document.getElementById('element')
              document.getElementById("texto").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data)
    
              console.log(data)
          })
          .catch(err => console.log(err))
    
    })
    }
      
    hola(busqueda)
    
    
        
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Aclaraciones:

- El input donde el usuario escribirá el identificador y lo asignamos a una variable
- Obtenemos el div por medio de su id que es donde se pintará la información recueparada
- Con el uso de backticks encerramos toda la URL y le pasamos de forma dinámica en forma de variable el id que recibe la función
- Cuando invocamos a la función le pasamos accediendo al atributo value el input donde el usuario escribió el id a recueprar
- Hacemos uso del evento `keyup` para detectar cuando el usuario suelta la tecla y así obtener el valor ingresado
  *Importante invoca a la función al final para que el código haga su trabajo

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que element es el `input` por el que filtras. De no ser así solo tienes que editar `element.value` por el valor de ese `input`

**Sin arrow function:**

```js
var data = [
  {"id":1, "nombre":"Pepe"},
  {"id":2, "nombre":"Luis"},
  {"id":3, "nombre":"Jose"}
];
function filtrar(){
  document.getElementById("element");
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML= JSON.stringify(data.filter(function(item) {
      return item.id == element.value;
  }));
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="element">
<button onclick="filtrar()">Filtrar</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```

**Arrow function:**

```js
var data = [
  {"id":1, "nombre":"Pepe"},
  {"id":2, "nombre":"Luis"},
  {"id":3, "nombre":"Jose"}
];
function filtrar(){
  document.getElementById("element");
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML= JSON.stringify(data.filter(item=> {
      return item.id == element.value;
  }));
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="element">
<button onclick="filtrar()">Filtrar</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que deberías hacer es convertir ese resultado a un `JSON` con el método `JSON.parse()`.
Hacemos uso del método `find()` para que nos devuelva un único valor en base a la condición, en este caso, cuando coincidan los *id* nos devolverá nuestro objeto con los datos que requerimos.

```js
const form  = document.getElementById('form');
const input = form.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
// Data de prueba
let data = [
    {id: 1, name: 'Persona 1', edad: 10},
    {id: 2, name: 'Persona 2', edad: 20},
    {id: 3, name: 'Persona 3', edad: 30},
    {id: 4, name: 'Persona 4', edad: 40},
    {id: 5, name: 'Persona 5', edad: 50}
]
// Así recibes la data, una cadena en formato json
data = JSON.stringify(data);

form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Parseamos la data a json 
    let resultados = JSON.parse(data);

    // Obtenemos lo que se introduzca en el input
    let id = input.value;

    // Obtenemos solo el usuario que coincida con el id
    let mi_usuario = resultados.find(
        user => user.id == id
    );
    
    // Mostramos resultados
    console.log(mi_usuario);
});
```

```html
<form id="form">
    <input type="text">
    <button>Filtrar</button>
</form>
```